# Get Local Notification every sunday if events is there in that week

Tags: ios, notifications, nsdateformatter

I am scheduling a local notification which is give notification on every Sunday. But I want if next Week have any event then i will receive notification on Sunday. if there is no event in that week than skip notification on Sunday.I have Event Array.I will set

localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitWeekday;

so i receive notification On Sunday.how I skip it..??

Comment: every times the user open the app you can check if in next sunday there is an event. If there is schedule local notification.

Comment: but requirement is when application is close then also revive local notification..So every sunday how i check that week have event.

Comment: which events we talking about?

Comment: I have Event Array,that give hole year event dates.

Comment: ok so in this array you can know when there is and where there isn't.. right?

Comment: yes i also checked that week has any event.if yes then set notification.but for every sunday how its possible.

Comment: i think you should compare date of the event array and the user date. Now check if next sunday there is an event in array and then scheduled notification. I think that you can't set repeat interval, but you can check every times the user open the apps if there is an event or not

Comment: okey but i also do this as app is closed also.if user not open app with in month.then ..

Comment: yes if the user don't open the app there is a problem... and if you use push notification? Service like Pushwoosh.